# Using existing CSS selectors to apply styles across the Shadow DOM to custom elements

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, bem

This question likely has no single direct answer, but hopefully will lead to some best practices or common patterns to use when adapting an existing styles framework to new web component development.

For my case, I have a component `<custom-avatar>`, and it's all set up properly with self-contained styles and functionality, everything is just peachy.

In certain use cases, the application display needs to stack avatars, just one slightly overtop one other at a diagonal, and the pattern I'm following is using a simple component `<custom-composite-avatar>`. All this does is wrap the slotted content in a `<div>` with the correct styling class, but key aspect is retaining the composability for flexible re-use, like so:

```js
<custom-composite-avatar>
  <custom-avatar title="first"></custom-avatar>
  <custom-avatar title="second"></custom-avatar>
</custom-composite-avatar>
```

The tricky bit lies in the styles, which are imported from a monorepo that provides the same BEM-ish CSS and component CSS modules to other flavors of the component library like React, Vue, etc. I have the `avatar` and `composite-avatar` styles imported just fine, but forcing the intended overlap display is defined with the hierarchical selector `.my-composite-avatar.my-composite-avatar--medium .my-avatar {}`

So with `.my-composite-avatar` class applied to the div wrapper within `<custom-composite-avatar>` and the `.my-avatar` class applied to the wrapper within the `<custom-avatar>` and it's own Shadow DOM, that parent/child CSS selector is no good.

I doubt there is a silver bullet for this, but this seems like it will be a rather common scenario as more people migrate to Web Components while using existing styling systems. What approach makes the most sense to ensure that the composite component remains composable, and adaptation of existing selectors pain-free (or at least easy to communicate to other devs)? can this be solved with `::host` or `::slotted`, or will these cases require significant re-work?

Thanks for reading, your ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I would advice to become good friends with **CSS properties**
because they trickle down into shadowDOMs following CSS selectors.

- [CSS Custom Properties(variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)
- and [getPropertyValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)
- and [setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) if you want to be brutal and make Custom Elements change the outside world.

#### example

I have an [`<SVG-ICON>` element](https://iconmeister.github.io) taking configuration from attributes **OR** CSS properties
with my favorite lines of code:

```
let val = this.getAttribute(attr) 
           || 
          getComputedStyle(this)
           .getPropertyValue("--svg-icon-" + attr)
           .replace(/"/g, "")
           .trim();
```

Allows for your standard  attribute configuration:

```
  <svg-icon name="configuration" fill="grey"></svg-icon>
```

But more powerful (*simplified example*):

```css
  <style>
    body {
      --svg-icon-fill: "grey";
    }
    svg-icon[selected] { 
      --svg-icon-fill: "green";
    }
  </style>
```

```html
  <svg-icon name="messages" selected></svg-icon>
  <svg-icon name="configuration"></svg-icon>
```

---

#### CSS = *Custom String Scripting*

[image]

It doesn't often happen, but sometimes the simplest code makes me very happy.

There is no *Styling* restriction!

These 2 lines allow **any String you want** in CSS properties:

```
    .replace(/"/g, "")
    .trim();
```

#### Example

```
<style>
   [name*="globe"] {
      --svg-icon-tile: "rect:0,0,24,24,0,fill='blue'";
      --svg-icon-stroke: white;
   }
</style>
<svg-icon name="feather-icons-globe"></svg-icon>
```

The `--svg-icon-tile` has nothing to do with CSS, it is read (and parsed) by the [`<SVG-ICON>`](https://iconmeister.github.io) `connectedCallback()` code to generate a SVG background/tile for all icons named *globe*.

The **double-quotes** aren't required, but without them your IDE will complain about invalid CSS.

Have fun coding... you will pull some hairs when you start with [calc() in your CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)...
But you can take 'CSS' to another level.

#### PS.

And monitor the future of **ConstructAble StyleSheets** aka **ConstructIble StyleSheets** aka **Constructed Sheets** aka **AdoptedStyleSheets**:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets
- https://chromestatus.com/feature/5394843094220800

iconmeister

Comment: Awesome, thanks Danny for the comprehensive solution. More than anything it is clear that to make our Web Component based UI kit the best we are going to have to reimagine how styles are baked into the components, rather than just try to roll with the large BEM-ish/SMACCS styling we already have. Totally changes the scope of the task. New strategies like this are going to be really powerful when we start our new approach.

Comment: Added a very important PS. [Constructable Style Sheets](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets). Supported in Chromium browsers; [Mozilla is working on it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1520690). And Apple is Apple. and (IMHO) BEM and WebComponents is like putting a horse in front of a Tesla

Comment: Interesting approach, even though I believe that the future are Constructable Style sheets as you say in the second part of the answer. Right now I am using litelement, and have constructs like export const myCss css ...that will be imported and used in the modules. And this should become more perfomant with Constructables. (and dynamic imports)

Comment: It's an awesome design pattern. Thank your for recommendation. I've revised my code and it worked!