# :host-context not working as expected in Lit-Element web component

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

I've got two Lit-element web components - one is `units-list`, which contains many `units-list-item` elements.  The `units-list-item` elements have two different display modes: compact and detailed.  Because the list element supports infinite scroll (and thus could contain several thousand units), we need any mechanism that toggles between the two modes to be as performant as possible.

That's why I thought an ideal solution would be to use the `:host-context()` pseudo-selector in the styles for the `units-list-item` element, as that way every `units-list-item` element could switch between the two display modes just by changing the class applied to an ancestor (which would be within the shadow DOM of the `units-list` element).

To elaborate, here's the relevant markup from the `units-list` element. Note that the "trigger" classes are being applied to the `#list-contents` div, which is part of the `units-list` template.

```
<div id="list-contents" class="${showDetails ? 'detail-view table' : 'compact-view table'}">
    ${units.map(unit => html`<units-list-item .unit="${unit}"></units-list-item>`)}
</div>
```

As you can see, the `showDetails` flag controls whether the "detail-view" or "compact-view" class is applied to the div containing all of the `units-list-item` elements.  Those classes are definitely being applied correctly.

Here's the full render method from the `units-list-item` element (unnecessary markup removed):

```
render() {
    const {unit} = this;
    // the style token below injects the processed stylesheet contents into the template
    return html`
        ${style}
        <div class="row compact">
            <!-- compact row markup here -->
        </div>
        <div class="row detail">
            <!-- detail row markup here -->
        </div>
    `;
}
```

Then I have the following in the `units-list-item` element's styles (we're using SCSS, so the single-line comments are not a problem):

```scss
    // This SHOULD hide the compact version of the row when the 
    // unit list has a "detail" class applied
    :host-context(.detail-view) div.row.compact {
        display: none !important;
    }

    // This SHOULD hide the detail version of the row when the
    // unit list has a "compact" class applied
    :host-context(.compact-view) div.row.detail {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

My understanding of the :host-context selector says that this should work, but Chrome just renders both versions of the row every time, and the Chrome dev tools show that the selectors are never matching with either of the rows.

I know there are several alternatives that would work, but this is the only one I'm aware of that would allow the entire list of units to switch modes by changing a single class on a parent element.  Every other solution I've considered would require, at the least, updating the class attribute on every `units-list-item` element in the list.  I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Of course, my primary concern is simply to make this work, if possible, but I'm also curious about a couple of things and can't find any info about them. The two questions I can't seem to find an answer for are

1. When `:host-context` is used within an element that is itself part of a shadow DOM, does it consider that parent element's shadow DOM to be the "host context", or does it jump "all the way out" to the document DOM?
2. If it's the former, will `:host-context` jump multiple shadow DOM boundaries? Say I have a custom `page` element that contains a custom `list` element, which itself contains many custom `item` elements. If that `item` element has a `:host-context` rule, will the browser first scan up the shadow DOM of the `list` element, then, if matching nothing, scan up the shadow DOM of the `page` element, and if still matching nothing, then scan up the main document DOM to the `<html>` tag?

Comment: At second sight it looks like you have a typo.. **:host-content** Experiment in a JSFiddle. I don't have one because there is no support for ``:host-context`` in FireFox or Safari; last update from a month ago is both Mozilla and Apple are **not** going to implement it. Looks like it is going to be removed from the spec: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1914 One alternative is to use CSS Properties (those trickle down into shadowDOM)

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the typo, but it was only in the question, not in the actual code. And custom properties would be fine if I was trying to just change a color, but I'm trying to get an element to display/not display based on a parent element's class. That's not something custom properties are really suited for.

Comment: I did [a quick JSFiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/dannye/yx8kLaf4/) extending on the MDN example, works fine. Are those ``!importants`` your Nemesis? Using ``important`` is a sure way to get into trouble eventually; avoid them with Specificity.

Comment: No, I only added the `!important` after everything else had failed to work.  The fact that your fiddle works and my code doesn't suggests to me that the issue has something to do with nested web components. The fact that this isn't supported by Firefox means that this is a non-starter anyway, so I'll have to turn to an alternative solution.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: And why are CSS properties not suited? That, and forcing with JS, is the only way to get the 'outside' into shadowDOM. You are not restricted to styling, you can stuff any string value in CSS properties.

Comment: So far we've only used custom properties for one type of use case; I hadn't even considered you could do things like redefine the value of a custom property by matching a certain parent selector.  You win the prize :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no support for `:host-context` in FireFox or Safari**

It will be removed from the spec:
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1914

One alternative is to use CSS Properties (those trickle down into
shadowDOM)

#### JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/hpd6yvxt/

- using `host-context` for Chrome and Edge
- using CSS properties for other Browsers

## Update Feb 2022

https://caniuse.com/?search=host-context

[image]

## Update Feb 2023

[image]

Comment: Thanks man!  I think I'll just go the custom property route for everything - doesn't make a lot of sense to split the implementation for such a small benefit, considering custom properties should be as (if not more) performant than the `:host-context` selector.

Comment: What are "CSS properties" here? CSS variables?

Comment: Yes, formal name is: **CSS Custom Properties** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 4):

An example of using css porperties, as Danny Engelman says, to get your goal

```js
  customElements.define('list-item', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const style = document.createElement('style');
      const divcompact = document.createElement('div');
      divcompact.innerHTML = "compact";
      divcompact.className = "compact";
      const divdetail = document.createElement('div');
      divdetail.innerHTML = "detail";
      divdetail.className = "detail";
      let shadow = super().attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      });
      shadow.append(style, divcompact, divdetail);
      style.innerHTML = `
      .compact {
          background-color: red;
          display: var(--display-compact, block);
      }
      .detail {
         background-color: green;
          display: var(--display-detail, block);
      }
      `
    }
  });
```

```css
.compact-view {
  --display-detail: none;
}
.detail-view {
  --display-compact: none;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;  
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    no class applied
        <list-item>test</list-item>
    </div>
    <div class="compact-view box">
    compact view
        <list-item>test</list-item>
    </div>
    <div class="detail-view box">
    detail view
        <list-item>test</list-item>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that you could change the value of custom properties by defining them in class selector rules like that.  Had to give credit to the other guy for the answer but I've upvoted your answer as well.

Comment: You can do a lot more with CSS properties; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327555/using-existing-css-selectors-to-apply-styles-across-the-shadow-dom-to-custom-ele/61329821#61329821

Comment: Great answer! I adapted yours to this much simpler one for beginners like me: https://codepen.io/lerner-zhang/pen/Vwgpeav