# Can the CSS :part pseudo-selector be used to style nested web components?

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

When creating Web Components with encapsulated styles using Shadow DOM, parts of the shadowed markup can be styled using the ::part pseudo selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part).

Can the part selector be used to target nested shadow parts?

```
<custom-element>
  #shadow-root
    <div part="thats-easy"></div>
    <another-custom-element part="proxy-part">
      #shadow-root
        <div part="target-me"></div>
    </another-custom-element>
</custom-element>
```

Current efforts were fruitless:

````
another-custom-element::part(target-me) { }
custom-element::part(proxy-part) another-custom-element::part(target-me) { }
custom-element::part(proxy-part another-custom-element::part(target-me)) { }
custom-element::part(proxy-part::part(target-me)) { }
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fun twist, it is possible and TIL about `exportparts`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/exportparts

### Example 1

```html
<style>
  mux-player::part(textspan) { color: red; }
</style>

<mux-player>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <media-poster-image exportparts="poster, img, innerspan: textspan">
      <template shadowrootmode="open">
        <img part="poster img" src="...">

        <span part="innerspan">
          This text will be red because the containing shadow host forwards innerspan to the document as "textspan" and the document style matches it.
        </span>

        <span part="textspan">
          This text will not be red because textspan in the document style cannot match against the part inside the inner custom element if it is not forwarded.
        </span>
      </template>
  </template>
</mux-player>
```

### Example 2

Example in production with multiple nested custom elements with CSS parts.
https://github.com/muxinc/elements/blob/main/packages/mux-player/src/template.ts

Comment: [Further reading about using `exportparts`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220908033421/https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/css-shadow-parts-1.md)

Comment: Future readers: My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74044803/how-to-position-nested-shadow-doms-on-top-of-each-other) here demonstrates how `exportparts` is used with nested components.

Comment: @luwes, would you mind adding an example of how it works for the code in the question? I think it would benefit future readers to have an example here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. It is not possible. It kind a breaks the encapsulation principle. The right way is to use proper theming. That means using a combination of:

```
::part - For direct theming of the component
:host-context - for theming based on the context
::slotted - For styling the slotted element inside the styling
```

For more dynamic theming, you can use above styles in combination with [`Element.matches` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). Whatever the class/context that the user of the component has set, you can then change the styling of nested children component.

> On a side note, modifying the styling of a decadent component (children of children) is a bad practice even when not using Shadow DOM or Web Components. It will result in a brittle non-maintainable CSS.

Edit Note:

`:host-context` is not implemented in all browsers and probably never will.

Comment: Be careful with ``::host-context``, limited support, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532839/host-context-not-working-as-expected-in-lit-element-web-component/61545226#61545226\

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That is right.