# How to position nested shadow DOMs on top of each other?

Tags: css, nested, web-component, shadow-dom

Is it possible to position nested shadow DOMs on top of each other?

With normal DOM, nested divs just stack by default:

```css
.d1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: darkslateblue;

}
.d3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">
      <div class="d3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But with shadow DOM, how can this be done?

```js
id = 0;
depth = 3;
customElements.define('box-component', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    if (id > depth) 
        return;
    this.id = id++;
    
    var template = document.getElementById("box-template");
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
    
    // The only goal of all of the following boilerplate is to set 'exportparts' attribute,
    // such that each parent exports its *descendants* (not just *children*) parts.
    // This is done by accessing the shadow dom of the child from its parent.
    // (note: the outermost component doesn't need to export its parts)
    if (id == 0)
        return;
    
    const parts = [...this.shadowRoot.children]     
      .filter(elem => elem.getAttribute('part'))
    
    let thisExportParts = null;
    let childExportParts = null;
    
    thisExportParts = parts.map(elem => [
      [elem.getAttribute('part'), `${elem.getAttribute('part')}${this.id}`].join(':')
    ].join(','));
    
    if (this.shadowRoot && this.shadowRoot.children) {
        const childShadowRoot = 
        [...this.shadowRoot.children].filter(elem => elem.shadowRoot)[0];
      if (childShadowRoot) {
        const fullChildExportParts = childShadowRoot.getAttribute('exportparts');
        if (fullChildExportParts) {
          childExportParts = fullChildExportParts.split(',').map(part => {
            return part.includes(':') ? part.split(':')[1] : part;
          }).join(',');
        }
      }
    }
    this.setAttribute('exportparts', [thisExportParts, childExportParts].filter(_ => _).join(','));
  }
});
```

```css
box-component::part(box1) {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
box-component::part(box2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
box-component::part(box3) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<template id="box-template">
  <style> 
  </style>
  <div part="box"></div> 
  <box-component></box-component>
</template>

<box-component class="container"></box-component>
```

Comment: [Further reading about using `exportparts`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220908033421/https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/css-shadow-parts-1.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. In the shadow DOM, the following should be added:

```
:host { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
}
```

This `:host` rule styles all instances of the custom component element (the shadow host) in the document to be absolutely positioned, while also making the positioning *relative to each positioned parent* (that's why `top: 0` is needed).

In fact, this is similar to changing the normal DOM code in the question to use positioning (note that without positioning, just setting `top: 0` won't work ([further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent) [read](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824215240/https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-understand-css-position-absolute-once-and-for-all-b71ca10cd3fd/))):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.d1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: darkslateblue;

}
.d3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">
      <div class="d3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, here's the full code:

```js
id = 0;
depth = 3;
customElements.define('box-component', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    if (id > depth) 
        return;
    this.id = id++;
    
    var template = document.getElementById("box-template");
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
    
    // The only goal of all of the following boilerplate is to set 'exportparts' attribute,
    // such that each parent exports its *descendants* (not just *children*) parts.
    // This is done by accessing the shadow dom of the child from its parent.
    // (note: the outermost component doesn't need to export its parts)
    if (id == 0)
        return;
    
    const parts = [...this.shadowRoot.children]     
      .filter(elem => elem.getAttribute('part'))
    
    let thisExportParts = null;
    let childExportParts = null;
    
    thisExportParts = parts.map(elem => [
      [elem.getAttribute('part'), `${elem.getAttribute('part')}${this.id}`].join(':')
    ].join(','));
    
    if (this.shadowRoot && this.shadowRoot.children) {
        const childShadowRoot = 
        [...this.shadowRoot.children].filter(elem => elem.shadowRoot)[0];
      if (childShadowRoot) {
        const fullChildExportParts = childShadowRoot.getAttribute('exportparts');
        if (fullChildExportParts) {
          childExportParts = fullChildExportParts.split(',').map(part => {
            return part.includes(':') ? part.split(':')[1] : part;
          }).join(',');
        }
      }
    }
    this.setAttribute('exportparts', [thisExportParts, childExportParts].filter(_ => _).join(','));
  }
});
```

```css
box-component::part(box1) {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
box-component::part(box2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
box-component::part(box3) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<template id="box-template">
  <style> 
    :host { 
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <div part="box"></div> 
  <box-component></box-component>
</template>

<box-component class="container"></box-component>
```